# Remove Horizontal Whitespace Between Matplotlib Plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I am generating a subplot in Matplotlib that features four subplots stacked in a vertical orientation. The plot looks as follows:

[image: Four Panel Subplot]

In order to generate the subplots, I am currently utilizing GridSpec to govern whitespace between the plots and overall layout of each plot. I have included `gs.update(wspace=0.00, hspace=0.00)`, however this has not removed whitespace in between the top three subplots as I anticipated. The expanded code is as follows, please note that I've only included the key pieces for simplicity:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8), sharex=True, sharey=True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1, height_ratios=[1, 1, 1, 11.5])
gs.update(wspace=0.00, hspace=0.00)
bar_width = 0.40

botax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
im = plt.imshow(clds_arr, cmap='Blues', vmin=0, vmax=100, interpolation='nearest')
for i in range(len(clds_arr)):
   for k,j in zip(clds,range(len(objects_temps))):
   if k in list(range(0,51)):
   text = plt.text(j, i, clds_arr[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="k", fontsize=11)
else:
   text = plt.text(j, i, clds_arr[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="w", fontsize=11)

midax = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharex=botax)
im = plt.imshow(temps_arr, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='nearest')
for i in range(len(temps_arr)):
   for k,j in zip(temps,range(len(objects_temps))):
      if k in list(range(-10,5)) + list(range(15,25)) + list(range(88,99)):
         text = plt.text(j, i, temps_arr[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="w", fontsize=11)
      else:
         text = plt.text(j, i, temps_arr[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="k", fontsize=11)

upperax = plt.subplot(gs[2], sharex=botax)
im = plt.imshow(dpts_arr, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='nearest')
for i in range(len(dpts_arr)):
   for k,j in zip(dpts,range(len(objects_temps))):
      if k in list(range(-10,5)) + list(range(15,25)) + list(range(88,99)):
         text = plt.text(j, i, dpts_arr[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="w", fontsize=11)
      else:
         text = plt.text(j, i, dpts_arr[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="k", fontsize=11)

topax = plt.subplot(gs[3], sharex=botax)
rectstop = plt.bar(ymax_pos, height=highheight, width=0.65, bottom=min_highhght, color='#1e90ff', edgecolor='black', linewidth=2, zorder=3)
for rect in rectstop:
    y_value = rect.get_height()+min_highhght
    x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
    space = 2
    va = 'bottom'
    label = y_value
    plttxt = plt.annotate(label, (x_value, y_value), xytext=(0, space), textcoords="offset points", ha='center', va=va)
    plttxt.set_fontsize(13)
    plttxt.set_weight('semibold')
```

What additional code is required to remove the additional whitespace in between the top three subplots? Thanks!

Comment: try putting `gs.update` at the end of the script instead of the beginning

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PaulH! I included that at the end of the subplot chunk and there was no change to how it appears above. I also commented out fig.tight_layout() to see if that might be the culprit, but neither produced the desired result.

Comment: Try aspect=“auto” in your imshow call.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code as you present it since there are so many undefined variables.

However, when I run a minimal version, I get what you seem to want:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot, gridspec 
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(14,8), sharex=True, sharey=True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1, height_ratios=[1, 1, 1, 11.5])

botax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
midax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharex=botax)
upperax = fig.add_subplot(gs[2], sharex=botax)
topax = fig.add_subplot(gs[3], sharex=botax)

gs.update(wspace=0.00, hspace=0.00)
```

[image]

Comment: I did get a similar result when pairing gs.update with Jody's call of plt.imshow(aspect='auto'). When running this, I get a lot of extra white space to the left & right of the plot [figsize=(14,8)]. When I correct this with gs.tight_layout(fig), I lose the tight spacing with gs.update. Any ideas why?